# Customising the default wordpress search functionality

Tags: filters, query, search, wpdb, sql

I find the current from WordPress too strict as it doesn't allow for some minor spelling mistakes. How can I edit this function?

I was checking out pre-get-posts however I don't think that allows me to change the SQL calls (or does it?)

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: You can change the value of `s` and other query vars using `pre_get_posts`, WP search isn't especially smart though. If you want fuzzy search etc you'll want to integrate something built for search like Elastic Search or Algolia, WP search is very primitive, and there's only so much that MySQL can do

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer. Have you got any info/links on changing the 's' value? I cant find anything on that. If I was to change the SQL, I would probably be looking at only changing it if there was nothing returned?

Comment: The `s` value is literally just the raw search string, you can see it in the URL and its set by the search field ( which is an input tag with `name="s"`, there's very little to talk about, it's just a string. E.g. to add a word to a search query, add a word to the `s` query vars value. I suspect you think there is more going on but there isn't. WordPress search is extremely simple and unsophisticated. There's no relevance or fuzzy search, WP just asks the database for all posts that have the words in the search string in their title or content and orders them by date, that's it

Comment: Fair. So when you say change the 's' are you saying to change the search value? How would that work? So they search "blgo" which returns no posts. What did you have in mind when you said change the 's' value? Literally having a function in PHP which checks for the word 'blgo' then changes it to 'blog'?

Comment: That is the only way I can think of doing it within WordPress without involving external 3rd party software designed for search, but that would be impractical. IMO what you want is not feasible without installing software designed for search

Comment: I see, So would the wordflow be to add a PHP function in the results page and check the length of the posts and if there are no posts returned then send another query with the string - 3 characters

Comment: I'd actually add autocorrect suggestions under the search box, it would be easier and could be done with javascript. Modifying WP search itself is going to be painful, a proper search solution would do all of this easily though, have you looked into services such as https://www.elasticpress.io/ or installing software on your server for search?